# javascript passing two values using button

Tags: javascript

How do you pass two values using a button? My values are value="" data-value="CPS210-CompSci-I (4)".

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" name="grade" value="<?php echo " $cs1 "; ?>" data-value="CPS210-CompSci-I (4)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education "></span> Grade
</button>
<script>
  $('button[name="grade"]').click(function() {
    var grade = $(this).val();
    //var cs=$(this).
    $('#grade').html("<h4> Grade recived " + grade + "</h4>");
    $('#cs').html("<h4>" + cs + "</h4>");
  });
</script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p id="grade"></p>
  <p id="cs"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the getter version of `.data()` to access your required `data-attribute`,

```
$('button[name="grade"]').click(function() {
  var grade = $(this).val();
  var cs = $(this).data("value"); // .data("dataAttributeName")
  $('#grade').html("<h4> Grade recived " + grade + "</h4>");
  $('#cs').html("<h4>" + cs + "</h4>");
});
```